# determine shape from x,y change in python

Tags: python, geometry

Im using python to track the x,y change of a mouse over a period of time in order to detect a shape. For example, a diagonal line going southwest would have an x-y change of `[1,1]`, and a v shape might have a pattern of `[[1,1],[1,-1]]`.

This works well when the shape is constructed in the same direction and from the same point as before, however, you can construct a square from four different starting positions in either clockwise or counter-clockwise fashion. If we were to try and detect all possible configurations, the list would look like:

```
# Clockwise
[[0,1],[1,0],[0,-1],[-1,0]]
[[1,0],[0,-1],[-1,0],[0,1]]
[[0,-1],[-1,0],[0,1],[1,0]]
[[1,0],[0,1],[-1,0],[0,-1]]

# Counter-Clockwise
[[0,-1],[1,0],[0,1],[-1,0]]
[[-1,0],[0,-1],[1,0],[0,1]]
[[0,1],[-1,0],[0,-1],[1,0]]
[[-1,0],[0,1],[1,0],[0,-1]]
```

Is there a way i could test if a given list of x,y change would form a square without having to make a lookup table for each possibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can! If you expect the shape to be made up of the same `n` points, but only traversed either in order or in reverse from any starting point, then you can check if you can pull out all of the points in order without skipping except at the end of the array:

```
def verify_candidate(candidate, reference):
    candidate_start = candidate[0]
    if candidate_start not in reference or len(candidate) != len(reference):
        return False
    rfi = reference.index(candidate_start)
    for pti in range(len(candidate)):
        if candidate[pti] != reference[rfi]: # if, at any index, there is a mismatch, then fail.
            return False
        rfi = (rfi + 1) % len(reference)     # avoid index error
    return True

verify_candidate(user, square)
verify_candidate(user, list(reversed(square)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sets instead of lists and tuples instead of lists for keeping track of xy changes (you cannot use lists inside of sets because lists are mutable and hence can't be hashed).

```
square = {(0,-1), (1,0), (0,1), (-1,0)}
user_mov = {(1,0), (0,-1), (-1,0), (0,1)}
square == user_mov
# True
```

If the movement might contain a point twice, and you want to make sure it occurs twice you cannot use sets and instead can sort the lists and compare them

```
square = [[0,-1], [1,0], [0,1], [-1,0]]
user_mov = [[1,0], [0,-1], [-1,0], [0,1]]
sorted(square) == sorted(user_mov)
# True
```

Comment: This is not robust to point re-shufflings. One could draw a "Z" or a square using the same points in different orders.